# Error :No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found. Visual studio 2017 enterprise instead of MinGW

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, mingw, intel-fortran

I have a project,configured and Generated in `cmake-gui` with `mingw` succesfully .

but when I want to configure or build it (`cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"`
) with `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` and `Intel Parallel Studio 2017 (Visual Fortran Compiler)` I get this errors:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.
```

so what should I do?

**EDIT:**

When I use `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"` I get:

```
-- The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/FreshElmer - Copy (3)/elmerfem/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "F:/FreshElmer - Copy (3)/elmerfem/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# 
# CMake configuration script for Elmer
# 
# Authors:
#  Sami Ilvonen, CSC - IT Center for Science, Ltd.
#  Phil Weir, NUMA Engineering Services, Ltd.
#  Mikko Byckling, CSC - IT Center for Science Ltd.
#  Juhani Kataja, CSC - IT Center for Science Ltd.
#
# First public beta release 11th of October, 2013
#

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo" CACHE STRING "Build type (Release, Debug, RelWithDebugInfo, MinSizeRel)")
ENDIF()

PROJECT(Elmer Fortran C CXX)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)

IF(APPLE)
  SET(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1) 
ENDIF()

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules)

# Defaults to cache variables
SET(WITH_MPI TRUE CACHE BOOL "Use MPI parallelization")
SET(MPI_TEST_MAXPROC 8 CACHE STRING "Maximum number of tasks used in parallel tests")
SET(MPI_TEST_MINPROC 1 CACHE STRING "Minimum number of tasks used in parallel tests")
SET(WITH_OpenMP FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use OpenMP thread parallelization")
SET(WITH_MKL FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use Intel Math Kernel library")
SET(WITH_Mumps FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use Mumps sparse direct solver")
SET(WITH_Hypre FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use Hypre linear algebra library")
SET(WITH_ELMERGUI FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include ElmerGUI")
SET(WITH_ElmerIce FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include ElmerIce")
SET(WITH_ELMERGUITESTER FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include ElmerGUI tester")
SET(WITH_ELMERGUILOGGER FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include ElmerGUI logger")
SET(ELMER_INSTALL_LIB_DIR "lib/elmersolver" CACHE PATH "Location of elmer shared libraries relative to prefix.")
SET(WITH_Trilinos FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use Trilinos")
SET(WITH_FETI4I FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use FETI4I")
SET(WITH_ELMERPOST FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include ElmerPost (DEPRECATED)")
SET(WITH_CONTRIB FALSE CACHE BOOL "Include contributed solvers")

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(WITH_ELMERPOST)

if("${CMAKE_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER 2.8.12)
  CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0022 OLD)
ENDIF()

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(ELMER_INSTALL_LIB_DIR)

ENABLE_TESTING()

SET(ELMER_FEM_MAJOR_VERSION 8)
SET(ELMER_FEM_MINOR_VERSION 3)
SET(ELMER_FEM_VERSION
  ${ELMER_FEM_MAJOR_VERSION}.${ELMER_FEM_MINOR_VERSION})

IF(NOT(ELMER_FEM_REVISION))
  SET(RESET_ELMER_REVISION TRUE CACHE BOOL "")
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(RESET_ELMER_REVISION)
ENDIF()

IF(RESET_ELMER_REVISION)
  execute_process(
    COMMAND "git" "--no-pager" "log" "-1" "--pretty=format:%h"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE ELMER_FEM_REVISION_
    RESULT_VARIABLE RUN_RETURN_VALUE)
  IF(RUN_RETURN_VALUE EQUAL 0)
    SET(ELMER_FEM_REVISION ${ELMER_FEM_REVISION_} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    MARK_AS_ADVANCED(ELMER_FEM_REVISION)
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()

SET(VERSION ${ELMER_FEM_VERSION})
SET(REVISION ${ELMER_FEM_REVISION})
SET(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
STRING(TIMESTAMP ELMER_FEM_COMPILATIONDATE "%Y-%m-%d")
SET(COMPILATIONDATE ${ELMER_FEM_COMPILATIONDATE})

# Check that the gfortran version is >= 4.8
IF(${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "GNU")
  INCLUDE(testGFortranVersion)
  IF(NOT CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_GNU_VERSION_OK)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "GNU Fortran version is too old, should be at least 4.8")
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()

IF(WITH_OpenMP)
  # Advanced properties
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
    OpenMP_C_FLAGS
    OpenMP_Fortran_FLAGS
    OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS
    )

  FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP REQUIRED)
  # Add OpenMP flags to compilation flags
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_Fortran_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
ENDIF()

IF(WITH_MPI)
  # Advanced properties
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
    MPI_EXTRA_LIBRARY
    MPI_LIBRARY
    )


  FIND_PACKAGE(MPI REQUIRED)
  # Workaround if MPI is found but MPI_FOUND is not set (windows+msmpi+findmpi)
  SET(MPI_FOUND TRUE CACHE BOOL "")
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(MPI_FOUND)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})
  # MPI libraries may be needed for testing
  SET(CMAKE_C_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${MPI_C_LIBRARIES})
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
  SET(CMAKE_Fortran_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF(WITH_MPI)

IF(WITH_MKL)
  # Find MKL
  FIND_PACKAGE(MKL REQUIRED)
  SET(HAVE_MKL TRUE)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(HAVE_MKL)
  # Set BLAS and LAPACK to point to MKL
  SET(BLAS_LIBRARIES ${MKL_BLAS_LIBRARIES} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  SET(LAPACK_LIBRARIES ${MKL_LAPACK_LIBRARIES} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  IF(MPI_FOUND)
    SET(SCALAPACK_LIBRARIES ${MKL_SCALAPACK_LIBRARIES})
    # Versions >11.1 of MKL include Cluster PARDISO direct solver
    IF(WITH_OpenMP AND MKL_CPARDISO_FOUND)
      SET(HAVE_CPARDISO TRUE)
      MARK_AS_ADVANCED(HAVE_CPARDISO)
    ENDIF()
  ENDIF()
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MKL_INCLUDE_DIR})
  SET(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${MKL_Fortran_FLAGS}")
ENDIF()

# MARK_AS_ADVANCED(WITH_Trilinos)
IF(WITH_Trilinos)
  FIND_PACKAGE(ML REQUIRED PATHS ${TRILINOS_PATH}/lib/cmake/ML ${TRILINOS_PATH}) 
  FIND_PACKAGE(Trilinos REQUIRED PATHS ${TRILINOS_PATH}/lib/cmake/Trilinos ${TRILINOS_PATH})
  FIND_PACKAGE(Belos REQUIRED PATHS ${TRILINOS_PATH}/lib/cmake/Belos ${TRILINOS_PATH})
  IF(ML_DIR)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_TRILINOS)
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()

# MPI and LAPACK
FIND_PACKAGE(BLAS REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(LAPACK REQUIRED)
# BLAS and LAPACK libraries may be needed for testing
SET(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES 
  ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES} ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})

IF(MPI_FOUND)
  # Mumps
  IF(WITH_Mumps)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Mumps REQUIRED)
  ENDIF()
  # Hypre
  IF(WITH_Hypre)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Hypre REQUIRED OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS Euclid parcsr_ls ParaSails IJ_mv QUIET)
  ENDIF()

  # Permon
  IF(WITH_FETI4I)
    FIND_PACKAGE(FETI4I REQUIRED)
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()

IF(Mumps_FOUND)
  SET(HAVE_MUMPS TRUE)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(HAVE_MUMPS)
  # LINK_DIRECTORIES(${MUMPS_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()

IF(Hypre_FOUND)
  SET(HAVE_HYPRE TRUE)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(HAVE_HYPRE)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Hypre_INCLUDE_DIR})
  # LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Hypre_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()

IF(FETI4I_FOUND)
  SET(HAVE_FETI4I TRUE)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(HAVE_FETI4I)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_FETI4I)
ENDIF()

# Check if Fortran compiler supports procedure pointer
INCLUDE(testProcedurePointer)
IF(NOT CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_PROCEDUREPOINTER)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Fortran compiler does not seem to support the PROCEDURE statement.")
ENDIF()

# Check if Fortran compiler supports contiguous keyword
INCLUDE(testContiguous)
IF(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CONTIGUOUS)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DCONTIG=,CONTIGUOUS)
ELSE()
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DCONTIG=)
ENDIF()

# Check if this is mingw toolchain. 
IF(MINGW)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DMINGW32)
ENDIF()

IF(WIN32)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DWIN32)
ENDIF()

# Check if Fortran compiler supports execute_command_line 
INCLUDE(testExecutecommand)
IF(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_EXECUTECOMMANDLINE)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_EXECUTECOMMANDLINE)
ENDIF()

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_ISO_C_BINDINGS)
SET(FC_STDCALLBULL " ")
SET(ELMER_LINKTYP 1)
#SET(FC_FUNC FC_GLOBAL)
#SET(FC_FUNC_ FC_GLOBAL_)

# Add support for arpack 
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_ARPACK)

#INCLUDE(FortranCInterface)
#FortranCInterface_HEADER(FCMangle.h MACRO_NAMESPACE "FC_")
#FortranCInterface_VERIFY(CXX)

# Set up rpaths to point ELMER_INSTALL_LIB_DIR
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")   
  SET(ELMERSOLVER_RPATH_STRING "\$ORIGIN/../${ELMER_INSTALL_LIB_DIR}")
  SET(ELMERLIB_RPATH_STRING "\$ORIGIN/")
ELSEIF(APPLE)                               
  SET(ELMERSOLVER_RPATH_STRING "@loader_path/../${ELMER_INSTALL_LIB_DIR}")
  SET(ELMERLIB_RPATH_STRING "@loader_path/")
ENDIF()

# Uncomment these to use rpath with linked libraries
# SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE) 
# SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
# Remove system directories (from the CMake guide)
# LIST(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" isSystemDir)
# IF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
#    SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
# ENDIF("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(matc)

IF(WITH_ElmerIce)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Adding optional package ElmerIce")
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(elmerice)
ENDIF(WITH_ElmerIce)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(umfpack)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(fhutiter)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(meshgen2d)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(fem)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(mathlibs)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(elmergrid)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(license_texts)

IF(WITH_ELMERGUI)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Building ElmerGUI")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ElmerGUI)
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERGUI)

IF(WITH_ELMERGUITESTER)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ElmerGUItester)
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERGUITESTER)

IF(WITH_ELMERGUILOGGER)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ElmerGUIlogger)
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERGUILOGGER)

#INCLUDE(FeatureSummary)
#FEATURE_SUMMARY(WHAT ENABLED_FEATURES
#  INCLUDE_QUIET_PACKAGES
#  DESCRIPTION "Enabled Features:"
#  VAR enabledFeaturesText)
#MESSAGE(STATUS "${enabledFeaturesText}")

# 
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  STRING(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPCASE)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPCASE)
ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  BLAS library:   " "${BLAS_LIBRARIES}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  LAPACK library: " "${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  Fortran compiler:        " "${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  Fortran flags:           " "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPCASE}}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  C compiler:              " "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  C flags:                 " "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPCASE}}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  CXX compiler:            " "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "  CXX flags:               " "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_UPCASE}}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
IF(WITH_MPI)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran:             " "${MPI_Fortran_FOUND}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran compiler:    " "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILER}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran flags:       " "${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran include dir: " "${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran libraries:   " "${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI Fortran link flags:  " "${MPI_Fortran_LINK_FLAGS}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C:             " "${MPI_C_FOUND}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C compiler:    " "${MPI_C_COMPILER}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C flags:       " "${MPI_C_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C include dir: " "${MPI_C_INCLUDE_PATH}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C libraries:   " "${MPI_C_LIBRARIES}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  MPI C flags:       " "${MPI_C_LINK_FLAGS}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
  IF(WITH_Mumps)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Mumps:             " "${Mumps_FOUND}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Mumps include:     " "${Mumps_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Mumps libraries:   " "${Mumps_LIBRARIES}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
  ENDIF(WITH_Mumps)
  IF(WITH_Hypre)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Hypre:             " "${Hypre_FOUND}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Hypre include:     " "${Hypre_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "  Hypre libraries:   " "${Hypre_LIBRARIES}")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
  ENDIF(WITH_Hypre)
ENDIF(WITH_MPI)

IF(WITH_Trilinos)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Trilinos:           " "${Trilinos_FOUND}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Trilinos_DIR:       " "${Trilinos_DIR}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Trilinos_LIBRARIES: " "${Trilinos_LIBRARIES}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
ENDIF(WITH_Trilinos)

IF(WITH_CONTRIB)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Building contributed solvers")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
ENDIF(WITH_CONTRIB)

IF(WITH_ELMERGUITESTER)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Building ElmerGUI tester")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERGUITESTER)

IF(WITH_ELMERGUILOGGER)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  Building ElmerGUI logger")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERGUILOGGER)

IF(WITH_ELMERPOST)
  MESSAGE(WARNING "  Building ElmerPost")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(post)
ENDIF(WITH_ELMERPOST)

# Packaging
if(NOT BYPASS_CPACK)
  INCLUDE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpack/ElmerCPack.cmake)
endif(NOT BYPASS_CPACK)
```

**CMakeError.log:**

```
Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26730.10.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The system can not find the file specified.
The operation could not be completed 

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]

The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file or project file.
You can also use any other file as the first argument if you want to have the
file open automatically in an editor. When you enter a project file, the IDE
looks for an .sln file with the same base name as the project file in the
parent directory for the project file. If no such .sln file exists, then the
IDE looks for a single .sln file that references the project. If no such single
.sln file exists, then the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln
file name that has the same base name as the project file.

Command line builds:
devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ] [ /project projectnameorfile [ /projectconfig name ] ]
Available command line switches:

/Build      Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms
        are possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
/Clean      Deletes build outputs.
/Command    Starts the IDE and executes the command.
/Deploy     Builds and then deploys the specified build configuration.
/Edit       Opens the specified files in a running instance of this
        application. If there are no running instances, it will
        start a new instance with a simplified window layout.
/LCID       Sets the default language in the IDE for the UI.
/Log        Logs IDE activity to the specified file for troubleshooting.
/NoVSIP     Disables the VSIP developer's license key for VSIP testing.
/Out        Appends the build log to a specified file.
/Project    Specifies the project to build, clean, or deploy.
        Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
/ProjectConfig  Overrides the project configuration specified in the solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
        possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
        Must be used with /Project.
/Rebuild    Cleans and then builds the solution or project with the
        specified configuration.
/ResetSettings  Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to
        the specified VSSettings file.
/ResetSkipPkgs  Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
/Run        Compiles and runs the specified solution.
/RunExit    Compiles and runs the specified solution then closes the IDE.
/SafeMode   Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
/Upgrade    Upgrades the project or the solution and all projects in it.
        A backup of these files will be created as appropriate.  Please
        see Help on 'Visual Studio Conversion Wizard' for more
        information on the backup process.

Product-specific switches:

/debugexe   Open the specified executable to be debugged. The remainder of 
        the command line is passed to this executable as its arguments.
/diff       Compares two files.  Takes four parameters:
        SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceDisplayName(optional),
        TargetDisplayName(optional)
/TfsLink    Opens Team Explorer and launches a viewer for the 
        provided artifact URI if one is registered.
/useenv     Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables
        instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.

To attach the debugger from the command line, use:
    VsJITDebugger.exe -p <pid>


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26730.10.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The system can not find the file specified.
The operation could not be completed 

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]

The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file or project file.
You can also use any other file as the first argument if you want to have the
file open automatically in an editor. When you enter a project file, the IDE
looks for an .sln file with the same base name as the project file in the
parent directory for the project file. If no such .sln file exists, then the
IDE looks for a single .sln file that references the project. If no such single
.sln file exists, then the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln
file name that has the same base name as the project file.

Command line builds:
devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ] [ /project projectnameorfile [ /projectconfig name ] ]
Available command line switches:

/Build      Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms
        are possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
/Clean      Deletes build outputs.
/Command    Starts the IDE and executes the command.
/Deploy     Builds and then deploys the specified build configuration.
/Edit       Opens the specified files in a running instance of this
        application. If there are no running instances, it will
        start a new instance with a simplified window layout.
/LCID       Sets the default language in the IDE for the UI.
/Log        Logs IDE activity to the specified file for troubleshooting.
/NoVSIP     Disables the VSIP developer's license key for VSIP testing.
/Out        Appends the build log to a specified file.
/Project    Specifies the project to build, clean, or deploy.
        Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
/ProjectConfig  Overrides the project configuration specified in the solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
        possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
        Must be used with /Project.
/Rebuild    Cleans and then builds the solution or project with the
        specified configuration.
/ResetSettings  Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to
        the specified VSSettings file.
/ResetSkipPkgs  Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
/Run        Compiles and runs the specified solution.
/RunExit    Compiles and runs the specified solution then closes the IDE.
/SafeMode   Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
/Upgrade    Upgrades the project or the solution and all projects in it.
        A backup of these files will be created as appropriate.  Please
        see Help on 'Visual Studio Conversion Wizard' for more
        information on the backup process.

Product-specific switches:

/debugexe   Open the specified executable to be debugged. The remainder of 
        the command line is passed to this executable as its arguments.
/diff       Compares two files.  Takes four parameters:
        SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceDisplayName(optional),
        TargetDisplayName(optional)
/TfsLink    Opens Team Explorer and launches a viewer for the 
        provided artifact URI if one is registered.
/useenv     Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables
        instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.

To attach the debugger from the command line, use:
    VsJITDebugger.exe -p <pid>


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26730.10.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The system can not find the file specified.
The operation could not be completed 

Use:
devenv  [solutionfile | projectfile | anyfile.ext]  [switches]

The first argument for devenv is usually a solution file or project file.
You can also use any other file as the first argument if you want to have the
file open automatically in an editor. When you enter a project file, the IDE
looks for an .sln file with the same base name as the project file in the
parent directory for the project file. If no such .sln file exists, then the
IDE looks for a single .sln file that references the project. If no such single
.sln file exists, then the IDE creates an unsaved solution with a default .sln
file name that has the same base name as the project file.

Command line builds:
devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ] [ /project projectnameorfile [ /projectconfig name ] ]
Available command line switches:

/Build      Builds the solution or project with the specified solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms
        are possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
/Clean      Deletes build outputs.
/Command    Starts the IDE and executes the command.
/Deploy     Builds and then deploys the specified build configuration.
/Edit       Opens the specified files in a running instance of this
        application. If there are no running instances, it will
        start a new instance with a simplified window layout.
/LCID       Sets the default language in the IDE for the UI.
/Log        Logs IDE activity to the specified file for troubleshooting.
/NoVSIP     Disables the VSIP developer's license key for VSIP testing.
/Out        Appends the build log to a specified file.
/Project    Specifies the project to build, clean, or deploy.
        Must be used with /Build, /Rebuild, /Clean, or /Deploy.
/ProjectConfig  Overrides the project configuration specified in the solution
        configuration. For example "Debug". If multiple platforms are
        possible, the configuration name must be enclosed in quotes
        and contain platform name. For example: "Debug|Win32".
        Must be used with /Project.
/Rebuild    Cleans and then builds the solution or project with the
        specified configuration.
/ResetSettings  Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to
        the specified VSSettings file.
/ResetSkipPkgs  Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.
/Run        Compiles and runs the specified solution.
/RunExit    Compiles and runs the specified solution then closes the IDE.
/SafeMode   Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
/Upgrade    Upgrades the project or the solution and all projects in it.
        A backup of these files will be created as appropriate.  Please
        see Help on 'Visual Studio Conversion Wizard' for more
        information on the backup process.

Product-specific switches:

/debugexe   Open the specified executable to be debugged. The remainder of 
        the command line is passed to this executable as its arguments.
/diff       Compares two files.  Takes four parameters:
        SourceFile, TargetFile, SourceDisplayName(optional),
        TargetDisplayName(optional)
/TfsLink    Opens Team Explorer and launches a viewer for the 
        provided artifact URI if one is registered.
/useenv     Use PATH, INCLUDE, LIBPATH, and LIB environment variables
        instead of IDE paths for VC++ builds.

To attach the debugger from the command line, use:
    VsJITDebugger.exe -p <pid>


Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.26730.10.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
...
```

...